# M2 hdbscan binary & rosetta not working as expected python 3.9.6

Tags: macos, anaconda, cython, hdbscan, rosetta-2

I am trying to import hdbscan into my conda environment and it is failing to import. I have tried cloning from source as well as installing rosetta 2 but nothing seems to be working.

```
 import hdbscan
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/bcenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hdbscan/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .hdbscan_ import HDBSCAN, hdbscan
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/bcenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ._hdbscan_linkage import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/bcenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hdbscan/_hdbscan_linkage.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/bcenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hdbscan/_hdbscan_linkage.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/bcenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hdbscan/_hdbscan_linkage.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/bcenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hdbscan/_hdbscan_linkage.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
(bcenv) MacBook-Air-3:babycenter_scraper_work user$ softwareupdate --install-rosetta
Installing Rosetta 2 on this system is not supported.
(bcenv) MacBook-Air-3:babycenter_scraper_work user$ /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta
Installing Rosetta 2 on this system is not supported.
(bcenv) MacBook-Air-3:babycenter_scraper_work user$ sudo /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
Password:
Installing Rosetta 2 on this system is not supported.
```

---

I have Cython version 0.29.37 installed as well as hdbscan version 0.8.34rc1

Has anyone ran into a similar issue?

Comment: What hardware is this on?  AArch64 aka [arm64] macs should already have Rosetta-2 installed, otherwise they couldn't run any x86-64 binaries.  You still can't mix x86-64 and AArch64 in the same process, though, so you need to run x86-64 Python if you want to import x86-64 libraries.  Or build arm64 libraries if you can.

Comment: Why is an **osx-64** version of HDBSCAN installed? Conda Forge provides **osx-arm64** builds. Would help to see `conda info` and `conda list -n bcenv` to better understand the context - please edit question body to include those. Also, you can [check in Rosetta is already installed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/427970).